# Open a view getting nid from previous view

Tags: views

I have two view. One is a Gallery view and the other is a 
view with exposed filter with which i choose field_gallery[nid] to make operations into some editable fields.What i wish to Know  is if i can add a link in the first view with which open second view calling the [nid] of the first.
Do you think is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

You can do the following

1. In the first view add nid field
2. In the field settings go to rewrite result
3. In rewrite result give something like Link Text

[nid] will work as a place holder for the current content nid. You can see all the replacement patterns with in the view itself.

Comment: Thanks Mohammed.. I had no thought to rewrite function. But how tell to the field "go to view_name/?[nid] etc..etc"

Comment: hope you got that working now.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the first view to display a link to the second view (with exposed filter) so that the nid from the first view passes to the second view for exposed filter to work,

extending Mohammed Shameem's answer which gives you the correct way to add the link, you also need to take care of the URL format.

Exposed filters usually have a identifier in the url of format:

```
www.abc.com/cde/?fgh=ijk
```

Here fgh is identifier and ijk is the value passed.

So you need to construct URL in that format.